# Burp and jar files usage for python files in command prompt

Tags: python, jar, command-prompt, burp

I'm using python 3.3 and working on an assignment where in i have to create a python script that takes in list of url's from the command prompt and runs burp suite on each of them dynamically.so i looked for sample demo code to get familiar with burp and found this one: Helloworld.py

```
from burp import IBurpExtender
from java.io import PrintWriter
from java.lang import RuntimeException

class BurpExtender(IBurpExtender):
    def registerExtenderCallbacks(self, callbacks):

        # set our extension name
        callbacks.setExtensionName("Hello world extension")

        # obtain our output and error streams
        stdout = PrintWriter(callbacks.getStdout(), True)
        stderr = PrintWriter(callbacks.getStderr(), True)

        # write a message to our output stream
        stdout.println("Hello output")

        # write a message to our error stream
        stderr.println("Hello errors")

        # write a message to the Burp alerts tab
        callbacks.issueAlert("Hello alerts")

        # throw an exception that will appear in our error stream
        raise RuntimeException("Hello exception")
```

The problem which i am facing is, IDLE constantly pops error stating that java.io not found

```
from java.io import PrintWriter
ImportError: No module named java.io
```

or

```
from burp import IBrupExtender
ImportError: No module name burp
```

that's cos it's a java library so i downloaded a jython standalone jar file and burp suite too and i passed it in command prompt along with the filename as

```
java -jar jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar -Xmx1024m burpsuite_pro_v.1.5.14.jar HelloWorld.py
```

but its still not working. I have all the three files in the same folder. Any suggestions? What needs to be done inorder to make this demo work? am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Suggestions please!?! :(

Comment: Common guys i'm still stuck with it

Comment: Am i suppose to keep bumping this thread inorder to get noticed and get some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to their [documentation](http://portswigger.net/burp/help/extender.html#options_pythonenv) you can't directly use it with Python. However, you can use Jython (Python for the Java platform).

Things you will have to do if you use Eclipse IDE:

1. Go to Eclipse Marketplace (Help > Eclipse Marketplace) and look for `PyDev` plugin. Install it.
2. You will download [Jython-standalone](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.python%22%20AND%20v%3a%222.5.3%22) jar file and configure Jython interpreter: Window > Preferences > PyDev > Interpreter-Jython. Click New. Type for interpreter name: Jython. For Interpreter executable, click browse and browse to Jython-standalone jar file. (Click OK, NEXT...)
3. To create a Jython project: New > PyDevProject. Enter name of project. Under "Chose project type" select Jython. Under "Interpreter" choose Jython. Click OK.
4. Now, how to add `burp.jar` to buildpath. Right click on your project > Properties > Select External Libraries tab > Add zip/jar/egg. Browse for `burp.jar` and finally click OK.
5. Create new PyDevModule, choose  template. and you are ready to go.

Good luck!

Comment: I'll try this and let you know...Thanks @brano88